# RemoteSwingLIbrary RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I downloaded the jar file from [here](https://github.com/robotframework/remoteswinglibrary) and put it in `PYTHONPATH`.

**Executed the test**

> **C:\Users\panda18\Desktop\Free_software\jsoftphone\jsoftphone>**`pybot test.txt`

**Getting the below error:**

```
    [ ERROR ] Error in     file 'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Free_software\xxxx\test.txt': Importing test     library 'RemoteSwingLibrary' failed: ImportError: No mod
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      None
    PYTHONPATH:
   C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\RTS\CONF_FILE
   C:\windows\system32\python27.zip
   C:\Python27\DLLs
   C:\Python27\lib
   C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
   C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
   C:\Python27
   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL

   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
```

Comment: Can you show the test to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Followed the link provided by you. I just have, reproduced the issue mentioned by you as you see below:

[image]

Then you need to set the `PYTHONPATH` to include the *remote swing library* as mentioned there in the link. You may notice in the screen shot that there is **no remote swing library found in the `PYTHONPATH`**.

*Used below command to set on the command prompt:*

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Users\apps\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.0.3.jar
```

> **Note:** You may replace the path in the above command as per your environment. And of course, you may also set `PATHONPATH` in **environment variables** of your system as well if you do not want to set the each time in command window.

Now again the run the test, `pybot test.txt` and do not see the mentioned error any more.