# RobotFramework - Unable to import RemoteSwingLibrary

Tags: python, swing, testing, robotframework

Screenshot of error in RobotFramework

[image]

Hello, I am trying to use the RemoteSwingLibrary in RobotFramework for testing.  Other libraries I have been able to pip install just fine.  However, RemoteSwing is not available with pip.  I have a jar file of the library in the python27 folder with other libraries and have it explicitly listed in the path variable.  Still receiving the error message that it does not see the module.  Please advise.  Thank you!

Comment: Don't post images of text! Copy/paste the text itself.

Answer (score 1):

As the library is as jar file, Python interpreter with Python will not read it. You need to use Jython(java based python implementation)+Robot instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your issue is that you don't have it in the PYTHONPATH system/user variable.

This you can clearly see in the bug report where is listed.

You can [add it to the system variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0) or use robot with a parameter where the path is specified:
`robot --pythonpath c:\python37-32\libs\remoteswinglibrary-2.2.3.jar`

btw. The guy from the different answer is absolutely missing the point. This is also part of the instruction for the installation RemoteSwingLibrary for pybot too and the reason for the existence of this project. The manual for installation is [here](https://github.com/robotframework/remoteswinglibrary#installation).

You can look also here where is [almost the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954387/remoteswinglibrary-robotframework).